# Ag Grid Prevent Column from changing during sort

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have the following Column definition

```
<AgGridColumn headerName="Rank" cellRendererFramework={NodeIDRenderer} suppressFilter={true} suppressSorting={true} lockPosition/>
```

And the Cell renderer it's using is this

```
import React from 'react';

class NodeIDRenderer extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div>{Number(this.props.node.id) + 1}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default NodeIDRenderer;
```

What I am trying to do is have this Column be a way to Rank other Columns when they are sorted. So I want this Column to always start a 1 and go to N. The issue I am facing is that when I sort any of my other columns this Rank column also changes. Is there a way to "lock" the column so the data never moves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `node.rowIndex` rather than the `node.id`. The id gets set once to maintain a unique reference to the node, the index is updated on any sort or filter. I did notice that the filter had a tendency to be a little unreliable with the row, so I called the `refreshCells` function of the grid api when the filter was updated. [Here is a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/v5yjkenfBP3RGpblxBj3?p=preview) you can test with.

Comment: Thanks man! This is exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate it.

Comment: For some reason when I sort any of my columns by 'ascending' the refresh does not seem to work.